# How to check Allowed Attachment File Size in Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am using Amazon SES for sending mails in a custom PHP project. I am facing a couple of issues.

1) The amazon ses allows me to send small sized pdf files. Where i can change the file size limit? I am unable to find it.

2) The amazon ses just allows pdf files to be sent. Whenever I try to send any other file type it says illegal file name. Please tell me how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

While the default is 10 MB, in 2021 it is now possible to request Amazon increase your maximum message size to up to 40 MB as per https://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/#49.

Answer (score 1):

AWS SES mail size limit is 10MB. It will allow PDF's and many other file types, but there are restrictions.

You can read more here: http://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/#49

If you need to send a restricted file type, you can rename the file before it goes out and the recipient would have to know enough to rename it when it arrives (which is a pain), so I use a backup SMTP server in those cases.

Comment: I know about the 10Mb limit but the problem is that it is not allowing me to send any file of more than 1mb or so....Let me know about this please.....